# Responsive site working on mobile in test but not in build

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm currently learning React and trying to build a simple website. [Here it is](https://codesandbox.io/s/1r5zx4j7rl) on Codesandbox.

I want the site to be responsive, and I've added what I believe to be the necessary CSS and HTML, like `@media screen and (max-width: 600px)` and `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">`

The site displays as expected in the browser, tested on Chrome and Firefox.

My problem is that when I run the site on the development server with `npm start` it behaves nice and responsive on the phone. However when I run `npm run build` and then serve it from a web-server with URL and all, the phone just displays it as a zoomed out desktop site. I've tried this on an Android and an iPhone.

I've searched but can't find a similar problem.
I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was that where I got my URL used a www-forwarder that wrapped my page in a frame. This ruined the responsiveness.
By changing the URL to a DNS service instead, the wrapper was removed and my site worked as expected.